# Where to find the source code of @types/node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

According to the instructions online, I installed Node for Typescript via the following command.

```
npm install @types/node --save-dev
```

I found that there were some new files in the directory `node_modules` after running the above command.

```
node_modules
    @types
        node
            index.d.ts
            package.json
            README.md
            types-metadata.json
```

If I recall correctly, Node.js was written in JS instead of Typescript, so I need to use those JS source codes to invoke Node.js api, instead of just the Typescript definition file shown above, but where can I find those files? What's the default location to store those JS files when I run `npm install @types/whateveritis`?

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node

Comment: @YOU Thank you for your comment. I just learned how to use typescript and nodejs, so maybe I didn't make my question clear. I mean, when I use typescript to invoke nodejs APIs, it cannot just use the `index.d.ts` file to do all the work, right? it has to rely on some other files(such as `fs.js`, etc.) to do the real work. So where does typescript find those files? I just tried to install another module: `npm install @types/sqlite3`, and I didn't find the `js` files, either.

Comment: you need `npm install sqlite3 --save` to install real library. Type hints are generally for your IDE and linters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JS files that make up a module aren't handled by TS. Node is part of the runtime environment, so it's always available. Other packages would be bound in node_modules. The type information is married with the actual module code when you do an import -- the TS compiler will find the appropriate type declaration for a module name (potentially from @types) and bring that in.

Keep in mind that TS never explicitly does anything with the modules you import, it just applies the proper type info for the compiler's own bookkeeping. Nothing is *actually* imported until you execute your generated javascript code and typescript is no longer relevant at that point.

Note that you did not install node by doing that, you will still need to install any modules separately through NPM. See earlier point of node always being available.